# calculating average of each session by unique itemID

Tags: r

i have a data frame

```
 > data
session id        item id 
  1                 1 
  1                 1
  1                 1
  2                 1
  2                 2
  3                 1
  3                 0
  3                 3
  3                 2
```

and i want to calculate avg of each session id like this uniqueitemsinsession/totalitems= ans (1/3=0.333)and get result like this

```
>  result   
session id       avg
   1             0.333
   2             1.000
   3             1.000
```

how can i do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can use dplyr package

```
data %>% group_by(session_id) %>% summarise(avg = length(unique(item_id))/length(item_id))
```

You have asked many questions on basic grouping and summarise operations in R. It would be better to go through [tutorials like this](https://www.listendata.com/2016/08/dplyr-tutorial.html) to learn all these tricks in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Try aggregating your dataframe on the `session id` column *against* the `item id` column - and pass the function you want, namely `mean`:

```
newDF <- aggregate(`item id` ~ `session id`, data, mean)
```

Those backticks should be necessary as your column names contain spaces.

Here are some [other alternative methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group) to get the job done.

–––

You could rename them using this:

```
names(data) <- c("col1", "col2")
```